# Game Help - Reset

Tags: flash

Okay so I'm making this game in flash and it's really complex so bear with me.
I want to make it so that when the"stopGame" function activates I'll be able to go back to Level One of my game but since going back to the "Level1" function would make duplicates of certain objects I had to make another function "Level1Reset"
My problem is although It can go to "Level1Reset" fine, it won't go to "Level2" after that so I'm perpetually locked in "Level1Reset"
I have included below a small sample of my code with only the code that is necessary for the functions I have described.
I realised I haven't given you much to work with but any help at all would be appreciated.

```
start_mc.play_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, Level1);

function Level1(e:MouseEvent):void {
    RanLetter = "FOURR";
}

function Level1Reset(e:MouseEvent):void {
RanLetter = "FOURR";
}

function stopGame(gameMessage:String):void {
    stop_mc.play_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, Level1Reset);
}

function NextLevel(gameMessage:String):void {
if(RanLetter == "FOURR") {
    stop_mc.play_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, Level2);
}else{
    if(RanLetter == "ROELL") {
        stop_mc.play_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, Level3);
    }else{
        if(RanLetter == "GRENN") {
            stop_mc.play_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, Level4);
        }else{
            if(RanLetter == "LAMBSHEPP") {
                stop_mc.play_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, Level5);
            }else{
                if(RanLetter == "SHORELLS") {
                    stop_mc.play_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, Level6);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function Level1(e:MouseEvent):void {
    RanLetter = "FOURR";
    stop_mc.play_btn.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, Level1);
}
```

Remove Event Listeners after used.